# How to perform OAEP padding on plaintext

Tags: python, rsa, pkcs#1

I'm studying RSA cryptosystem by reconstructing it. I know that padding is imperative for security of cipher, thus i've chosen PKCS1 OAEP padding since it's one of the most secure methods for padding message. I couldn't find exact simply understandable source for performing OAEP padding from my research.

```
>>> message = "Hello World"
>>> message_length = len(message)  # value: 11
>>> hash = sha1("").hexdigest() #  value: "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709"
>>> hash_length = len(hash)  # value: 40
>>> mod_size = (66707621741034658424514206418677753964865266688022969048429208771289785288847727334295743540860932900769628607474618294659295004562698532947535801821428015940719336654123007538255459184765551631213180128939808032261346408111382837800099426844454970753309552867519518744723276317986718923680385211621637413963).bit_length()  # size of public modulus (value: 1023)
>>> mod_size_bytes = -(-mod_size//8)  # size of public modulus in bytes, using ceil division
```

From research i found out that data above is necessary for performing PKCS1 OAEP padding, but i don't know how can it be utilized properly.

Are all necessary variables defined in the code? If so how can these variables be utilized to perform OAEP padding?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAEP padding algorithm is described at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-7.1.1.

Options:

- Your choice for Hash seems to be SHA-1.
- MGF-1 is really the only choice for MGF, so we can assume that one, too.

Inputs:

- You have the RSA key `n` value, but not `e` (though if you're writing the padding separate from the encryption you don't need `e`).
- You have `M` (some byte encoding of "Hello World")
- You have `L` = (the empty string).

Variables:

- You have `k` (mod_size_bytes)
- You have `mLen` (message_length)
- You have `lHash` (hash)
- You are missing `PS`, `seed`, `dbMask`, `maskedDB`, `seedMask`, `maskedSeed`, and `EM`

If you're writing your own OAEP padder, you'd implement 7.1.1 part 2.  Using the same names in your implementation as the spec usually leads to better error detection.